# Google Cloud Storage can't find project name

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-python-api

I am using the python client library for the Google Storage API, and I have a file, pythonScript.py, that has the contents:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# The name for the new bucket
bucket_name = 'my-new-bucket'

# Creates the new bucket
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)

print('Bucket {} created.'.format(bucket.name))
```

When I try to run it I get this in the terminal:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "pythonScript.py", line 11, in 
>       bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)   File "/home/joel/MATI/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py",
>   line 218, in create_bucket
>       bucket.create(client=self)   File "/home/joel/MATI/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py",
>   line 199, in create
>       data=properties, _target_object=self)   File "/home/joel/MATI/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py",
>   line 293, in api_request
>       raise exceptions.from_http_response(response) google.cloud.exceptions.Conflict: 409 POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=avid-folder-180918:
>   Sorry, that name is not available. Please try a different one.

I am not sure why, since I do have the GSS API enabled for my project, and the default configuration seems to be correct. The out output of `gcloud config list` is:

> [compute]
>
> region = us-east1
>
> zone = us-east1-d
>
> [core]
>   account = joel@southbendcodeschool.com
>
> disable_usage_reporting = True
>
> project = avid-folder-180918
>
> Your active configuration is: [default]

Comment: GCS has a global namespace of buckets (shared across all GCS users), and that bucket name ("my-new-bucket") already exists. You need to pick a different name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bucket names are globally unique. Someone else must already own the bucket named "my-new-bucket."